# How can I fix this error with Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-3.7

I am extremely new to coding with Python and in the tutorial I am following I have to install Tensorflow. However when I import Tensorflow to my python (2.6) I get an error message. I would like to fix this error before I get started actually coding.

I have been trying for 4 days to get rid of errors with Tensorflow in Miniconda3. I have tried installing select versions of Tensorflow but have had the best luck just doing: pip install tensorflow. I get the same error if I am in Command Prompt or PyCharm.

This is what I type to get the error message every time:

```
import tensorflow
```

In videos I have watched this is not the what is supposed to happen, what is suppose to happen at least in PyCharm is a message saying:

*Process finished with exit code 0*

***Here is the exact error message:***

```
C:\Users\StRUT\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:516: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
C:\Users\StRUT\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:517: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
C:\Users\StRUT\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:518: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
C:\Users\StRUT\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:519: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
C:\Users\StRUT\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:520: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
C:\Users\StRUT\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:525: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
C:\Users\StRUT\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:541: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
C:\Users\StRUT\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:542: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
C:\Users\StRUT\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:543: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
C:\Users\StRUT\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:544: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
C:\Users\StRUT\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:545: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
C:\Users\StRUT\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:550: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
```

I hope I gave you guys enough info to help me out because I would really like to start learning to code python with a clean slate.

Thanks in advance,
Blayke

Comment: It seems there is no error, just a bunch of warnings related to this module version.

Comment: correct the code formatting.

Comment: Since you're only beginning your programming experience with Python, I'll recommend using Python 3, as Python 2 will soon cease to have any official support.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the warning by doing:

```
pip install --upgrade numpy==1.16.4
```

to which the warning went away completely and the problem was resolved. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

These are not error messages, but warnings about deprecated functionality in numpy, which is being used by tensorboard and tensorflow. Warnings are not errors, so do not worry about this.

The only way to "fix" the warnings is by waiting for tensorflow developers to modify the code in order to not use deprecated functionality.

Answer (score 0):

These are only warnings, that TensorFlow is using some stuff that will soon not be available, if you wish to suppress it, you can run the file with

python -W ignore filename.py